# Single Sign On over Frontend and Backend

Tags: spring-boot, azure, single-sign-on

I have a Spring-Boot webservice (the backend). It has also some simple webpages to interact with the user (the old frontend).
And it has implemented SSO (Single Sign On).
That all is working fine.

Now the webpages are not good enough. The webservice should stay for REST but a new Angular SPA (Single Page WebApplication) will come to give better interaction with the user (the new frontend).

The question is how to handle the SSO now? Font- and backend will be separated if the new SPA will come.

I can imagine one of these but I do not know whats best.

- Redirect SSO authentication in the SPA to the webservice. SPA only gets a session-token from the webservice if auth is ok.
- Handle SSO in the SPA and remove it from the webservice. Does not seems right to me but what do I know.
- Handle it in both SPA and webservice. I would expect the auth of the webservice would be skipped automatically because it is SSO.

Whats the way to do it normally? Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

first, let's define what separation means here. If it means different hostname for the two, e.g., frontend.example.com and backend.example.com, then you can handle SSO in SPA and call backend APIs by attaching an access token for every request, and the backend will validate the access token for each request.